# Suggestion to make my threadpool setup safe, DRY, and scalable

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

Right now I'm spawning 3 threads to do some concurrent work, I have it set up using Threadpooling since I want all threads to run concurrently, but have all threads complete before continuing.  Here is the gist of the code:

```
_resetEvents = new ManualResetEvent[3];

_resetEvents[0] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(DoWorkA);
_resetEvents[1] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(DoWorkB);
_resetEvents[2] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(DoWorkC);

WaitHandle.WaitAll(_resetEvents);
```

But my methods all use the same code base, I've broken it up into the 3 methods only to set() the right thread.

```
private void DoWorkA(object o) {
    var workerClass = new WorkerClass();
        workerClass.Process();
    _resetEvents[0].Set();
}
private void DoWorkB(object o) {
    var workerClass = new WorkerClass();
        workerClass.Process();
    _resetEvents[1].Set();
}
private void DoWorkC(object o) {
    var workerClass = new WorkerClass();
        workerClass.Process();
    _resetEvents[2].Set();
}
```

Obviously it's not very DRY, since I would like to have 4 or maybe 5 threads, but want to make sure the Set() is setting the correct _resetEvent when it's complete.

Any suggestions on how I can safely do this and make it more DRY and scalable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use Tasks from the TPL instead of threads, and there's no need for the wait handles:

```
Action execute = () => { 
    var worker = new WorkerClass();
    worker.Process();
};

var task1 = Task.Run(execute);
var task2 = Task.Run(execute);
var task3 = Task.Run(execute);
Task.WaitAll(task1, task2, task3);
```

Or, alternatively:

```
Action execute = () => (new WorkerClass()).Process();

Parallel.Invoke(execute, execute, execute);
```

If you need to scale this to N items, you can switch to PLINQ or Parallel.For/ForEach, and use:

```
int numToRun = 42;
ParallelEnumerable.Range(0, numToRun).ForAll(i => (new WorkerClass()).Process());
```

Comment: Thanks Reed, but is this the most scalable?  I'm wondering if I wanted 5 threads concurrent, Task.WaitAll(task1, task2, task3, task4, task5) seems non-scalable

Comment: @MarkKadlec At some point, you can switch to using Parallel.For/Parallel.ForEach, or even PLINQ, if you are working against a lot of items.  In general, when doing a lot of items, you'll have a collection, so PLINQ and Parallel.For/ForEach become more appropriate.

Comment: @MarkKadlec Just gave you an "N" items sample ;)

Comment: @MarkKadlec Also, FYI, `WaitHandle.WaitAll` may fail if you're running on an STA thread (UI thread) or if you pass more than 64 handles, so it's not particularly scalable, either. ;)

Comment: Good point, luckily this is not a UI thread and I doubt there will ever be more than 10 concurrent threads, probably run 3 for the rest of this app but wanted to make sure it was coded in the best way for future tweaks.

Comment: Reed,one more question, I need to pass in a configuration variable (RecordThreshold) to the Action, but since it's static that's not possible.  How can I use the Parallel.Invoke on the Action, but have a variable passed into it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30013/discussion-between-reed-copsey-and-mark-kadlec)

Answer (score 1):

Something like [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx) maybe better.

Otherwise just treating incoming argument as index in an array may be enough:

```
private void DoWork(object index) 
{
    var workerClass = new WorkerClass();
        workerClass.Process();
    _resetEvents[(int)index].Set();
}

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(DoWork, 0);
```